# Idle transactions Hibernate / PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, jsp, postgresql, session

I got a problem with my web app developed with Hibernate 3 and postgres. The problem is that every signle query that is executed and commited does not release connection in pool (limit = 100). I did some queries to DB after an action (SELECT, INSERT, etc...) and I got the results:

QUERY:

```
SELECT pid, query, state FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

```
5436;"SELECT...";"idle" <- this is ok 
6776;"SELECT..." ;active" <- this is ok
5324;"COMMIT";"idle"    
6840;"COMMIT";"idle"    
6276;"COMMIT";"idle"    
4804;"COMMIT";"idle"    
5812;"COMMIT";"idle"    
2608;"COMMIT";"idle"    
2576;"COMMIT";"idle"    
3896;"COMMIT";"idle"    
4660;"COMMIT";"idle"    
692;"COMMIT";"idle"
```

As you can see the problem are transactions that are commited, they stay in connection pool and block it. Next actions cause this to grow and grow and when pool is overdosed i can't connect to DB. I know there is a way to manualy drop them (SELECT pg_terminate_backend()) but i prefer solution in Hibernate. Now let go to my code, maybe it will clear up.

This is example of method in my DBManager (class that executes queries and manages DB):

```
public List getGroups()
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

    try
    {
        session.beginTransaction();
        groups = session.createQuery( "from Group WHERE locked='FALSE' ORDER BY startHours" ).list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        // logs
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            session.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Any other methods are done the same way. My session factory is defined at class level:

```
  public class DBManager
  {

   SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    public DBManager()
    {

    }

     // METHODS HERE
  }
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong... Session is opened and closed via `try{}catch{}finally{}`. It seems that after a commit transaction is not properly closed.

Here is my hibernate.cfg:

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/szkola_plywania_test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool(use the built-in) -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</property>    

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> <!-- wynik pokazywany w konsoli -->

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> <!-- create - nadpisywanie, update - dopisywanie -->

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property> <!-- seconds -->

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.User" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.MailConfig" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.Group" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.Child" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.Term" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.Counter" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.Invoice" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.AgeGroup" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.GroupTerm" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.Instructor" />
    <mapping class="com.school.hibernate.dto.PassInstance" />
```

Answer (score 6):

`idle` is not a problem. It's just an open connection that does nothing.

`idle in transaction` would be a problem as those connection are actively keeping "locks" on data (which e.g. might prevent auto-vacuum from doing its job properly).

The result from pg_stat_activity that you have shown does not indicate any problem.

> *As you can see the problem are transactions that are commited, they stay in connection pool and block it*

No they don't "block it" (at least you have not shown any indication of that). The pool just keeps them open - this is what a connection pool does.

Opening a connection to a DBMS is a quite expensive operation, so it's good to keep them open to be re-used.

If you want to reduce the number of open connections (for whatever reason), then you need to configure your connection pool to do so (e.g. by lowering the "idle" timeout). You should show us the configuration of your connection pool in order to determine if everything is fine.

Comment: I've added my hibernate cfg file to 1st post. Also I've checked carefully this IDLE transactions. As they are more than 100 there is no posibility to connect to DB anymore, I have to kill them or restart the server.

Comment: @eBEER: then you have configured the connection pool to use too many connections. The Hibernate.cfg is **not** the connection pool configuration. That must be somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (updated hibernate.cfg). I've been trying to implement c3p0 to handle transactions, but I get an error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.log.MLog - seems that jar is not in my class path, but it's there, belive me (c3p0-0.9.1.jar+mchange-commons 0.2.2).

Comment: @eBEER: well you told c3p0 to open 100 connections. I don't know why Hibernate keeps opening new ones. But from a Postgres point of view, everything is "as requested".

Comment: I've added another version of c3p0 and now it works fine. Limit is always 100 and my app works fine. But there is one thing more I want to ask: When I execute SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state='idle'; there are multiple transactions with value of QUERY= SELECT TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL. What is that?

Comment: Ok, the problem has changed a little bit. It works fine but only for a certain time. I can notice that idle processes are gone after timeout, but c3p0 creates some idle processes that still stay and after reaching max size they slow down the app and block connections to DB. ERROR: fatal sorry too many clients - when executing query. Idle proces query in pg_stat_activity: "SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL"